# Jquery UI Tabs changing Body Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I've tried the below script to no avail. I have a series of tabs at www.1tryten.com.  The tabs auto rotate and change on mouseover.  I'm trying to have it so that the currently active tab sets the class for the body tag.  Essentially, if tab-1 is active then the body class would be tab-1 etc.  Is this doable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs({
    event: 'mouseover',
    fx: {
        opacity: 'toggle',
        duration: 'slow',
        show: function(event, ui) { $("body").addClass(ui.tab);}
    }
}).tabs('rotate', 5000, true);
});
```

Here's the code for the tabs

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabs-bottom ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"> 
    <div id="tabsone" class="tabsone ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style=""> 
    <img src="/images/mac-mini-banner.png">
        <h3>Mac Mini Security Mount.  New Mac Mini Mount.</h3>
</div> 
<div id="tabstwo" class="tabstwo ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide" style=""> 
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p> 
</div> 
<div id="tabsthree" class="tabsthree ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide" style=""> 
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p> 
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p> 
</div> 
            <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"> 
                <li id="tabone" class="tabsone ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabsone"><img src="/images/laptop-lock-tab-nav.png"></a></li> 
    <li id="tabtwo" class="tabstwo ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabstwo"><img src="/images/computer-lock-tab-nav.png"></a></li> 
    <li id="tabthree" class="tabsthree ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabsthree"><img src="/images/locker-tab-nav.png"></a></li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this:

```
$("body").addClass(ui.tab);
```

trying to assign to body the classes of ui.tab? Because addClass expects a string as its parameter. What you should be doing is:

```
$("body").attr('class', $(ui.tab).attr('class'));
```

... assuming that ui.tab is a valid object.

Comment: Wow I wish I understood Javascript better

Comment: Thanks so much matt.  Where would I add that to my existing javascript?

I believe the correct selecter would be li.ui-state-active

Comment: `show: function(event, ui) { $("body").attr('class', $(ui.tab).attr('class'));}`

Comment: I tried this as well as everyone elses answers and it isn't working.
Would you mind taking a look at my source code at www.1tryten.com quickly and letting me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use the select callback:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

--EDIT added code from website --

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
event: 'mouseover',
fx: {
    opacity: 'toggle',
    duration: 'slow'
},
show: function(event, ui) { 
    $("body").addClass(className);
}
```

});

A better explanation is here:  http://www.springenwerk.com/2008/03/jquery-ui-tabs-callbacks.html

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to javascript.  What would that look like in the script written in my question?

Comment: No worries.  Just put the select.. portion in your code after the fx: block (don't forget to put a comma after the end brace on the fx: block)  Do what you need to do such as addClass where the three dots are.  Essentially, it's a function inside a function.

Comment: I tried this as well as everyone elses answers and it I can't make it work. Would you mind taking a look at my source code at www.1tryten.com quickly and letting me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks.  The function class name is coming up as undefined on the JSdebugger

Answer (score -1):

You can use the select event which gets triggered whenever you select any tab.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs({
    event: 'mouseover',
    fx: {
        opacity: 'toggle',
        duration: 'slow',
        show: function(event, ui) { $("body").addClass(ui.tab);},

    },
    select: function(event, ui) { $("body").addClass($(ui.tab).attr('class'));}
}).tabs('rotate', 5000, true);
});
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working... mind taking a look at my source code at www.1tryten.com quickly and letting me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FX enables animations and the like.  The select callback is its own entity.  The example you presented wouldn't work.

Comment: The select should be outside fx it was my mistake before I posted it. I have edited my answer now.

Comment: Thanks so much shankar, but I still am not getting any results... is it possible my selector ui.tab is the problem?  I really appreciate your help

Comment: If you have used the default markup which JQuery ui provies to create tabs then ui.tab gives you the anchor element. Can you post the markup used for the tabs?

Comment: I've added the code for the tabs... you can also view the Jquery ui here: http://www.1tryten.com/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery-ui.min.js